# End-to-end encryption without user-keys interaction

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to have true end-to-end encryption even if the user is not involved in generating, selecting, transporting, or storing of the keys?

Comment: I guess you could create and encrypt the keys on the client without ever seeing them yourself. But the user should always be able to view the keys and verify them. Else the server could just send different keys to other clients or send fake keys to the client pretty easily

Comment: If it's correct, on e-mail traffic, exists some providers that offers end to end encryption and it seems that between the same provider accounts, it is not needed to care about any password. Do you meant this ? e.g. former Dark Mail

Comment: @GiaRui Yes, it can be. Is it then end-to-end?

Comment: @AlexCole of course it is possible, if the client app performs key functions on behalf of the user. If that is in scope of what you are asking.

Comment: it could also be possible if the key is tied to the user's password, or if the central service hands out keys (it is true end-to-end, but not trustworthy)

Comment: Are you talking only messaging apps? Cause https provides end to end encryption in your browser

Comment: Doesn't every website that supports HTTPS do this while remaining transparent to the end user?

Comment: @ChrisHoward HTTPS is typically point-to-point, not end-to-end, so there are some subtle (and not-so-subtle) differences in concept.